# How to locate app which installed a potentially malicious certificate?

Tags: malware, certificates

On my S8 (Oreo) today, I got the notification: There is a certificate installed that may or not monitor your internet traffic.

Did spyware install itself? Or is this normal?

I updated from 7.0 to 8.0 a week ago but this notification only showed up today, so I assume it's not a good thing and not part of the update.

Which app is monitoring me?

Comment: Depending on the device model, there should be credential storage that can be accessed on the Settings - Security (or similar), then check any suspicious user's installed certificates. Note that some apps need to install a custom certificate to work (e.g. decrypting SSL content by MitM technique), but usually they will request for user's permission explicitly to install the certificate.

Comment: @AndrewT. How do I know which one is monitoring me?  Got tons of installed certificates.